# Strongly complete completion of profinite group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be à profinite group and $\widehat{G}$ his profinite completion. I want to show (I hope it's true) that $\widehat{G}$ is strongly complete that is all normal subgroups of finite index are open sets.

For that I take $\widehat{N}$ a finite index normal subgroup of $\widehat{G}$ and try to find $N$ normal subgroup of finite index of $G$ such that $\widehat{N}=\ker\left(\varphi_N:\widehat{G}\to G/N\right)$. I tried $N=\theta^{-1}\left(\widehat{N}\right)$ where $\theta:G\to\widehat{G}$ but could not conclude.

Not rely with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180280) I think: I don't want a different definition of strongly complete but I want to check that somewath ($\widehat{G}$ here) is strongly complete.

Comment: For an answer see also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122465/strongly-complete-profinite-groups). It has been shown on MSE, too.

Comment: Thanks for the links: so I have to check that $\widehat{\widehat{G}}=\widehat{G}$ for $G$ profinite... any help?

Comment: Yes, I have help - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494672/profinite-completion-is-complete).

Comment: So it seems to be false: take $V$ an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space of infinite dimension and let $G=\widehat{V}$ (for the additive structure). Then $G$ is profinite but $\widehat{\widehat{G}}\neq\widehat{G}$. Right?